# Generic Python mapping with type constraints

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to model a simple message handling system in Python. The idea is to register functions that act as a message handlers based on the message type. Something like this:

```
class Message(Protocol):
    ...

class M1(Message):
    ...

def handler1(message: M1) -> None:
    return None

handler_container: dict[type[Message], Callable[..., None]] = {M1: handler1}

def handle_message(message: Message) -> None:
     handler = handler_container[type(message)]
     return handler(message)
```

That's the gist of it. I run into typing problems when I want to introduce different return types per handler and constrain it by the message type. Imagine this:

```
def handle_message(message: Message[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

What I want is to make sure that when I call `handle_message` I get the specified return type back.  Like this:

```
class M2(Message[int]):
    ...

def m2_handler(message: M2) -> int:
    ...

# or

class M3(Message[None]):
    ...

def m3_handler(message: M3) -> None:
    ...
```

I got to a point where I register all these somewhat like this:

```
handler_container: dict[type[Message[Any]], Callable[..., Any]
```

and then I had to `typing.Cast` when returning from `handle_message` but there are other problems like when I `inspect.signature` the handler, the type returned for the message doesn't pass the `issubclass` check, I get `issubclass() arg 1 must be a class` (the arg is `Message[NoneType]`).

Any ideas how I can achieve this type safety? I understand it may not be possible to fully statically type this so I'd be okay with casting if necessary. Open to any ideas, thank you!

Comment: I recently read through https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/ which includes good examples of how such things can be done today. I hope that helps

Comment: @PabloHenkowski While PEP 695 is somewhat relevant, I have to say I currently don't see in what way it helps solve this specific problem. But if I missed something and you see a solution there, please do post it as an answer. I would be very interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you intend to use this container of message handlers to **dynamically** (i.e. at runtime) add and retrieve handler functions, you can immediately forget about perfect type safety.

The type checker will never be able to tell you for example, whether or not a handler for a *specific* message type has been registered already or not. Even if your call to `handle_message` passes `mypy --strict`, you will never be able to infer from that, if that call succeeds or not. (That is just the dictionary-key problem with an additional layer of abstraction.)

Also, since type variables need to be bound to *something*, they cannot be used meaningfully in annotations outside of *some* binding scope. In other words, `dict[type[Message[Any]], Callable[..., Any]` for the registry is about as good as it will get for that handler dictionary.

That being said, if we **had** [higher-kinded type variables](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/548) already, it **would be** entirely possible to write a class for your handler container/registry that at least gave you a type safe *interface* in the sense that it would

1. **enforce** new registrations to be coherent, i.e. a new handler being registered would require its argument type and return type to correspond to the chosen message type, and
2. **ensure** a retrieved handler corresponds to the chosen message type in its argument/return type (if one exist at all).

We **could** (yes, still hypothetically) implement part of the mutable mapping protocol (specifically `__getitem__`/`__setitem__`) to mimic the interface you already had in mind and store the (less helpfully annotated) dictionary as a protected attribute underneath.

Here is an example of what that might look like in the future: (**The following is hypothetical and not currently valid/meaningful Python typing.**)

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
M = TypeVar("M", bound="Message[T]", args=1)


class Message(Protocol[T]):
    x: T


class HandlerContainer:
    _registry: dict[type[Message[Any]], Callable[[Any], Any]] = {}

    def __setitem__(
        self,
        msg_type: type[M[T]],
        handler_function: Callable[[M[T]], T]
    ) -> None:
        self._registry[msg_type] = handler_function

    def __getitem__(
        self,
        msg_type: type[M[T]],
    ) -> Callable[[M[T]], T]:
        return self._registry[msg_type]


handler_container = HandlerContainer()


def handle_message(message: Message[T]) -> T:
    handler = handler_container[(type(message))]
    return handler(message)
```

---

But unfortunately **we don't** have higher-kinded type variables, so right now, I am afraid you cannot do much beyond this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T")


class Message(Protocol[T]):
    x: T


handler_container: dict[type[Message[Any]], Callable[[Any], Any]] = {}


def handle_message(message: Message[T]) -> T:
    handler = handler_container[(type(message))]
    return cast(T, handler(message))
```

Usage:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
# ... import Message, handler_container

U = TypeVar("U")


class M1(Generic[U]):
    x: U

def handler1(message: M1[U]) -> U:
    raise NotImplementedError

class M2:
    x: int

def handler2(message: M2) -> int:
    raise NotImplementedError

class M3:
    x: None

def handler3(message: M3) -> None:
    raise NotImplementedError

handler_container[M1] = handler1
handler_container[M2] = handler2
# handler_container[M3] = handler3

output1 = handle_message(M1[str]())
output2 = handle_message(M2())
output3 = handle_message(M3())
reveal_locals()
```

Mypy output:

```
note: Revealed local types are:
note:     output1: builtins.str
note:     output2: builtins.int
note:     output3: <partial None>
```

(Notice that Mypy cannot detect we never added a `M3` handler.)